# How to make express vpn run automatically at startup

Tags: network-manager, vpn, startup-applications

I have:

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-44-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 610

```
Configure network connections > general configuration > automatically connect to vpn
```

not working, it just keeps being greyed out.

I have installed expressvpn  and it works fine from terminal but I have to turn it on everytime I start the PC.

How to make expressvpn start automatically?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Click on the 9 dots menu and type 'Startup'.

Click on Startup Applications.

Click on Add.

Name it something like Express VPN.

In the command section, enter:

```
expressvpn connect
```

Save it by clicking Add and it should automatically connect when you next start your computer. If expressvpn has any other terminal command options you can simply modify the command above to suit.

Comment: I typed: "expressvpn autoconnect true" in terminal and it works, thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. The only search result I looked at included just the one command to connect, and I'm not an ExpressVPN user so I had to look that part up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a new Acer Chromebook 315 and running Linux within it.  I use Express VPN for Linux on my Acer, and to configure auto-connect for Express VPN all I did was open the terminal and type "expressvpn autoconnect true" (without the quotes)    Tested and works.